# Reloading iframe and redirect parent issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm on the same domain I need to go thru a login form by code and redirect to some page, the login does a bunch of settings across internal servers.

I implemented a page with an iFrame

```
  <iframe id="iframe" src="<path to login page>" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

where I load the login page and populate the id/pwd and click the submit button by code and it works fine, the login after a few seconds comes with a logged in message

```
  .. args have the data pulled from DB
    var $myIFrame = $('#iframe');
    $myIFrame.contents().find("input#userID").val(arg1);
    $myIFrame.contents().find("input#userPwd").val(arg2);

    $myIFrame.contents().find("input#mybutton").trigger("click");           
   ...
```

if in this browser I manually type the redirected  page it works great all of the backend settings stick. It works even on another browser tab.  But if I set the redirected location by code all of my login settings go away.

```
window.location.href='<path of internal page>';
```

I tried placing a delay it didn't work

I tried wait until the iframe reloads but still it resets all of the login stuff when it redirects

```
$("#iframe").on("load", function () {
    window.location.href= ''<path of internal page>';
    });
```

What could I be missing?????

Comment: Thanks Nikhil ... I just got it... it needed the Defferred JQuery stuff.

Answer (score 0):

When you run script from code it will be executed withing the IFrame, but if you are running script from your console it will be executed directly in your main/parent page.

so, in your code you need to pass redirect command to your parent page using.

```
window.top.location = '<path of internal page>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried it but still my settings get lost I put an alert message in the wait until load section it seems to wait but when the location is set all my backend settings go away, is there some context stuff i may be missing?  This an aspx page where I'm combining scripted C#  with Javascript

Comment: are you populating Session Variables after login??

Comment: No just calling the redirect .... the reason I'm doing this is because the login does a bunch of stuff it is not feasible for me to redo I thought login the user by code and redirecting him/her should get that done easily

Answer (score 0):

```
var page_url = '<path of internal page>';
document.getElementById('your_iframe_id').onload = function() { 
    if(jQuery("#your_iframe_id").contents().find("body").hasClass('logged-in'))
    {                   
        window.location.href = page_url;
    }                                                   
}
```